# MySQL port or socket?

Tags: mysql, apache, security, database-performance

My Apache and MySQL server are on the same machine, and MySQL is configured to listen to localhost:3306

Are there any security or performance benefits with this configuration when compared to using a socket file instead of localhost and port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, for security, you'd want to move the MySQL to a separate machine outside of the demilitarized zone.  That is, it should be contactable by the web server, being on the same network, but blocked from incoming internet traffic.  That way, getting the web server doesn't also get you the database.

The world isn't perfect, and we sometime have to host things together.  As long as the **port is blocked by a firewall** to all traffic except the loopback, there should be little to no difference security wise between a port and sock file.

Comment: Thanks... No difference to security... what about performance? I suspect localhost will have slight edge over a socket file, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Performance... I would guess the same, that the loopback doesn't do any file IO in between and may be slightly faster.  That said, I have not researched it.  If scale/speed become an issue, you'd likely be looking at more nodes anyway, and at that point the database would be moved off the box the web server is on, and you'd have to a network connection.  With that in mind, I design so that it can be scaled and just use a network call.

Comment: Thanks - it goes along with my thinking but its been a few years since I've worked with folks knowledgeable about the subject.

Comment: Even LAN vs socket is not a big deal -- there are other performance issues to worry about first.

Comment: For performance, UNIX sockets are faster than TCP connection.